# How to get user id from JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to get user id from JWT token.
My JWT token has payload something like this:

```
{
  "username": "Steve",
  "is_admin": false,
  "id": 1
}
```

How do I get access to `user id`?
I actually want to update certain fields in database as per the id, that are for a specific user.

Secondly after gaining the access how do I get update the fields?

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="accounts/images/", null=True, blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('branch', 'year' ,'image',)
```

What will be the view to update these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `User` object associated with the current `request` object. This assumes the cookie being present means that the user has a logged-in session when visiting the view in question,

```
def update_profile(request):
    current_user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=current_user.pk)
    profile.update(field_a="value a", field_b="value b")  # etc, example only
    profile.save()
```

To make this possible, you also need to add the user relation as a `OneToOne` field within the `Profile` object:

```
from django.contrib.auth import User  # assuming no customisation has been done to User model

# All your other imports and code

class Profile(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="accounts/images/", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=False,
    )
```

Comment: what if I have customised User?

Comment: I tried something like this:
`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`
`User = get_user_model()`

But this won't work

Comment: The current user object should already be populated within the `request` object. Separately, if you're using a custom model then you should end up with the modified user model within the `User` object. From there you can query `User.objects.get(pk=your_pk)`.

Answer (score 1):

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        exclude = ()
```

**views.py**

```
import base64
import json
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateAPIView

class MyUserViewset(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    pagination_class = None

    def get_object(self):
        request = self.request
        token = http_auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        token = token.replace("Token ", "")
        user_json = json.loads(base64.b64decode(token.split(".")[1]))
        user_id = user_json['id']
        User = get_user_model()
        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        return user_obj
```

Comment: I have a customized user model instead of `User`. Do I need to replace `User` to my model, or something else has to be done?

Comment: No need to. The get_user_model function is already doing this.